# How to pass parameters using GET method to the html page which contains only frames

Tags: javascript, html, http

I have an issue regarding to pass the parameters using GET method.After submitting the form in which I have one param named param1, my application navigates on the html page which contains only frameset/frame.It contains two frames left and right, in which two different html pages are there. Is it possible to pass the param1 to the page contained in left frame and/or right frame ?

Comment: You can append the data to the end of the URL for the frame being retrieved. You post your original get request and have that data appended to the end of the url that is getting the frames.

Comment: @ james sorry but not getting what you are actually want to deliver...can you please elaborate it using example ??

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do some work around.

Like adding a control(dummy) setting its attribs making it not visible. You can set the param1 as the name or value of the control, that you can access using parent.->DOM concept.

Or else, you can just do a  in the parent frame, do a GET/POST from it to the frame,after load.
this might work.just give a try.